# How can i run a service for my android app to let the user return to the same activity and bypass login

Tags: android

I do not want to use sharedpreferences. There is some trickery that the user can use to gain unauthorized access if i use  sharedpreferences. How can i run a service that runs in the background even when the user swipes the application so i can return him to his user panel when he opens it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very very very bad idea.

Services can be shut down by the system at any point, without any warning, if the system needs to free memory. And then all your data will be gone.

There are hundreds of guides and posts around on how to setup a secure login system, with automatic login for authorized users. Do a quick google search and you'll find them quite fast.